# 17.10 cisco anyconnect vpn client

Tags: vpn, 17.10, client, cisco

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10. Unfortunately it affected quite some configurations of the OS and applications too.
I used a customized vpn client by cicsco systems, its called 'anyconnect'. You do download it personalized & preconfigured from the universities website. After upgrading the OS it does not start at all. Any hints ideas.
Since also other confugurations are affected e.g. it is an option to reverse the process of upgrading.

Comment: If I may make a suggestion, I would suggest that you contact your university's IT department and ask them for the proper configuration steps, and then use the OpenConnect VPN system that's available in the repositories.  OpenConnect is an Open-Source version of AnyConnect, all you need is the configuration profile to import or configure.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem.

```
sudo apt install libpangox-1.0-0
```

Fixed it for me.
For more information please have a look at [my blog](https://zngguvnf.org/2017-12-04--ubuntu-17-10-and-cisco-anyconnect.html).

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, links *can* die off.  It's strongly suggested you include relevant content from links rather than just the link, in case the link dies off and the data is still relevant (though irretrievable at that point)